# How to create a flat ramp out of stairs?

Tags: bezier-curves, vertices, edges

I need to create a flat ramp, I have tried to dissolve the edges but its not producing the desired outcome, any ideas?

My current setup:
[image]

If I dissolve edges I get the following:
[image]

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subdivided and extruded plane does the trick. See below:
[image]

Here the number of subdivisions is 7

Comment: Thanks @Lukasz-40sth did the trick, had to make a few additional tweaks but got there :)